# Undefined Constructor Enum Java

Tags: java, oop, collections, enums, constructor

I have the following code for my enum:

```
public class CoffeeFactory {

    public static enum Type {
        LONG_BLACK(4.0),
        FLAT_WHITE(4.75),
        MOCHA(5.5);

        private double price;

        Type(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }

    public static enum Ingredient {
        ESPRESSO(0.5),
        MILK(1),
        CHOCOLATE(1.5);

        private double cost;

        Ingredient(double cost) {
            this.cost = cost;
        }

        public double getCost() {
            return cost;
        }
    }

    public static Coffee CreateCoffee(Type type){
        ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();


        switch (type) {
        case FLAT_WHITE:
            ingredients.add(Ingredient.MILK);
            Coffee c1 = new Coffee(ingredients, type.FLAT_WHITE);
            return c1; //new Coffee(ingredients, Type.FLAT_WHITE);

            break;
        case LONG_BLACK:
            ingredients.add(Ingredient.ESPRESSO);
            return new Coffee(ingredients, Type.LONG_BLACK);

            break;
        case MOCHA:
            ingredients.add(Ingredient.CHOCOLATE);
            return new Coffee(ingredients, Type.MOCHA);

            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }



}
```

This is my code for creating a coffee:

```
import patt.Coffee.CoffeeFactory.Ingredient;

public class Coffee {
    Type type;
    double cost;
    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients;

    public Coffee(ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients, Type type) {
        this.type = type;

        this.ingredients = ingredients;

    }


    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return type.ordinal();

    }

    public String listIngredients() {

        return type.toString();
    }
}
```

The error im getting is in the line:

Coffee c1 = new Coffee(ingredients, type.FLAT_WHITE);

the constructor Coffee(ArrayList, CoffeeFactory.Type) is undefined. Could someone please explain and show me what I have done wrong or if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: I don't use java but my guess is that type.FLAT_WHITE is using System.Type or some equivalent of that call your enum something else

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Coffee c1 = new Coffee(ingredients, type.FLAT_WHITE);
```

should be *one* of the following:

```
Coffee c1 = new Coffee(ingredients, type);

Coffee c1 = new Coffee(ingredients, Type.FLAT_WHITE);
```

You probably want the first one. The variable `type` already contains a reference to the `Type` enum instance `FLAT_WHITE`.  You know this because you're in that branch of the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in this.

```
    public static Coffee CreateCoffee(Type type){
    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
    switch (type) {
        case FLAT_WHITE:
            ingredients.add(Ingredient.MILK);
            Coffee c1 = new Coffee(ingredients, Type.FLAT_WHITE);
            return c1; //new Coffee(ingredients, Type.FLAT_WHITE);
        case LONG_BLACK:
            ingredients.add(Ingredient.ESPRESSO);
            return new Coffee(ingredients, Type.LONG_BLACK);
        case MOCHA:
            ingredients.add(Ingredient.CHOCOLATE);
            return new Coffee(ingredients, Type.MOCHA);
        default:
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```